# How to Add Table header and Scrollbar in jtable. java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollbar

I am trying to add a Table **header** and **Scrollbar** in `JTABLE`, but I'm not getting what I want. I have tried with 3 different procedures, but did not come up with the right one. This code is for **Scrollbar**.

Can any one tell me how to add header. I can't add it just as `model.addRow()` because after that I have to get the values from the table and this method create problems with that. and How to add Scroll bar code too.

This is my Code

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();      
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
//JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);   //Try one
//new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED ); // Try 2


model.addColumn("ID");
model.addColumn("NAME");
model.addColumn("MODEL");
model.addColumn("P_Price");
model.addColumn("S_Price");
model.addColumn("Quantity");

table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);    
table.setBounds(10, 0, 457, 103);

//panel_1.add(new JScrollPane(table)); Try 3
//panel_1.add(scrollPane); //link to Try one
//table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); // link 2 Try 2

panel_1.add(table);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add headers do

```
String [] header={"name","age"};
String [][] data={{"akash","20"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"}};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
```

To add scrollbar do

```
JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(table);
js.setVisible(true);
add(js);
```

Full Code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Table extends JPanel{

    JTable jt;
    public Table(){

        String [] header={"name","age"};
        String [][] data={{"akash","20"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"},{"pankaj","24"}};


        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,header);

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450,63));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(table);
        js.setVisible(true);
        add(js);

    }

    public static void main(String [] a) {

        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        Table tab= new Table();
        jf.setTitle("Table");
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(tab);




    }

}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: It dont works. JUST table disappear.  I have to add table in a Panal. so i just edit it accordingly  
JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(table);
  js.setVisible(true);
  //add(js);
  panel_1.add(js);

Comment: Add it too and it works js.setBounds(10, 0, 457, 103);

Comment: I dint use js.setBounds() and it worked fine.Maybe the full code will help you out so I posted above.

Answer (score 6):

I fear that you may be messing yourself up by use of `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` something that does not work well with most Swing GUI's and in particular JTables displayed in JScrollPanes.

Suggestions:

- Don't use `null` layouts, don't call `setBounds(...)` **especially** on something that you want to display inside of scrollpanes.
- Add the JTable to the JScrollPane via the JScrollPane's constructor.
- Add the JScrollPane thus created to a JPanel that uses `BorderLayout` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Foo {
   private JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();

   public Foo() {
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); 

      model.addColumn("ID");
      model.addColumn("NAME");
      model.addColumn("MODEL");
      model.addColumn("P_Price");
      model.addColumn("S_Price");
      model.addColumn("Quantity");

      panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel_1.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   public JPanel getPanel1() {
      return panel_1;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Foo mainPanel = new Foo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel.getPanel1());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Don't even use `setBounds(...)` on your JScrollPane. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms different from the original one.

Comment: i used panels that was just a small part of whole code. any way thanks i solved it and posted it as own answer

Comment: @AdnanAli, ok  you solved it, but listen to the advice above, if you use null layout (indicated by .setBound()), when your program runs on other platform it won't promise you a consistency regarding to the position of your components, :P

Comment: plus one for `dont use setBounds()` explanation

Answer (score 4):

***Headers* :**

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
String cols [] = {"ID","NAME","MODEL","P_Price","S_Price","Quantity"};
model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols );
```

***Scrollpane* :**

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
panel1.add(jsp);

//....
add(jsp);// add scroll to frame not the panel
```

Note :

But remember that `null layout` is not considered as a good program design, especially when setting up non top level container with `.setBounds( )` since it won't guarantee a consistency on other platform regarding to the position of the component.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for the stuff was that I wasn't adding `setBounds(10, 0, 457, 103)` method in `JScrollpane.` Thanks everyone for your answers. Credits to @singakash

Here is the complete working code.

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();      
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    model.addColumn("ID");
    model.addColumn("NAME");
    model.addColumn("MODEL");
    model.addColumn("P_Price");
    model.addColumn("S_Price");
    model.addColumn("Quantity");
    table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


    table.setBounds(10, 0, 457, 103);   

    JScrollPane jp=new JScrollPane(table);
    jp.setBounds(10, 0, 457, 103);
    jp.setVisible(true);
    add(jp);
    panel_1.add(jp);
```

Comment: Don't even use `setBounds(...)` on your JScrollPane. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms different from the original one. Also, if singakash answered your question, don't forget to accept his answer.

Comment: then what would be replacement of setBounds() ? so that i can resize dynamically ?

Comment: That's ***exactly*** what the layout managers are for! You can find find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing). This includes links to the layout manager tutorials.